# How to return Sql error in Java SpringRestful WebService?

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services, spring-rest

How to handle error like sql error in Java SpringRestful WebService? i read arround internet it just can return some httprequest error. But what if i want to return error from sql?

here is what i do :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dynamicurl/{sp}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
    public String dynamicurl(@PathVariable("sp") String sp, HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException {
        String strParam="EXEC MyGloryStoredProcedure";
        try {
            userService.dynamicurl(strParam);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = e.getMessage();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return err;
    }
```

when i trying to generate the error by entering wrong Stored Procedure name, it should give me "Could not find stored procedure 'MyGloryStoredProcedure'." in my console
but it didn't return anything, when i execute the webservice, via web browser.. it just blank page. How to return the sql error properly?

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc